# ios post request to rails web service: step by step

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, web-services, post

anyone can give me a tutorial link or a step by step for this beginning question:

In rails, for the user resource, i have

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
  else 
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

How i can make a post to /users to create a new user without 3rd api sdk?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Develop a ios client app for rails webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732972/develop-a-ios-client-app-for-rails-webservice)

Comment: You should really refrain from asking the same question again. If you think that editing the original question would increase its value, go ahead and do so.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9518412/403846) should get you started. You can largely ignore that the target is a different framework/language than Rails since they're both just speaking HTTP/REST.